# Microsoft Flow - Get Query Result (DevOps) ordered hierarchically

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, devops-services

I'm facing the problem that the result of a DevOps query in microsoft flow is ordered by ID - which is not the sorting that I see when I'm executing the same query in DevOps itself.

Is it possible to get the hierarchically ordered result of the query in Microsoft Flow?